# Auth on specific controller functions Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am working on a Laravel 5.1 based system. I have a route resource:

```
Route::resource('applicant', 'ApplicantController');
```

So as we expect it has the following functions in the controller:

```
index, create, store, edit, update, delete
```

And what I want is to apply the middleware auth in the `index` function only. Normally, if you want to apply Auth on the entire controller, you need to do:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

But when I remove it and just do:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    return view('applicant.index');
}
```

It doesn't work. I've done this before and works fine.
This is in my `ApplicantController` I want the `create` function to be public and only apply login authentication on `index`. I won't be using `edit, update, delete`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

can you try

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'index']);
}
```

You can also do the reverse

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'delete']]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use the _construct method, because whenever the changes happen to a particular controller, developer would have to change it on each controller specifically. The best option is to add auth function inside the route and specify controllers. If you've any problems with the provided auth function, you could create one and specify it on the kernal.